# Why calling window.alert() is slower than alert() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I read the following paragraph from the "JavaScript succinctly" book.

> Being explicit (e.g. window.alert() vs. alert()) costs a little bit more with regard to performance. It's faster if you rely on the scope chain alone and avoid explicitly referencing the head object even if you know the property you want is contained in the global scope.

Why calling the `window.alert()` (with referring head object explicitly) is slower than `alert()`?

I thought calling explicitly cuts the chain searching for the method and addresses it directly so it should be faster!

It's confusing!

Comment: The book is from succinctly series, and it tells about topics so briefly. That's why it doesn't explain the details. But it made the question in my head!

Comment: Towards the actual question: it's implementation dependent. I'd expect parsing more symbols, and a non-native object reference resolution to be slower, compared to the native scope chain implementation. It may however also be, that a smart optimization catches this, and changes that part in the result of the jitter, should that code snippet be jitted. Whatever it is, the difference is so small, that any other factor, most dominantly any minor change in code readability, will make this irrelevant.

Comment: Hint. `alert`, `window.alert`, `window.window.alert`, `window.window.window.alert`, etc... all do the same thing.

Comment: Just to stress this again: any source, that does statements like this, should always make it crystal clear, not to obsess over this, and fall into the trap of premature optimization. Actively thinking about these (irrelevant) things while programming, is terribly damaging.

Comment: @bishop the link you mentioned is almost the answer. It shows that the statement from the book is correct, but I still don't understand why. Thank you BTW.

Comment: @Rahmani "Why is window.alert slower than alert" is indeed a different question, and a good one, IMO. Please edit this question to ask "why" (rather than "is it slower", which duplicates) and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @bishop I edited the question. tnx.

Comment: `window.alert()` doesn't cut any chain searching because it now needs to search the scope chain for `window`. You optimized a scope chain lookup (`alert`) to a scope chain lookup (`window`) + a property lookup (`alert`).